# Modelsim export wave (bitmap) batch mode

Tags: scripting, tcl, batch-processing, modelsim, questasim

Currently I run Mentorgraphics Modelsim in batch mode for a few nightly simulations.
My simulations run fantastic and in my transcript files I can see all errors/warnings/etc. but it would be nice to see the waveform for every simulation in a image, too, without simulating the projects again (it takes a long time...).
Modelsim/Questasim is able to export this bitmap in GUI mode (Select wave window and go to menu bar: "File -> Export -> Image").

Is there any opportunity to save the waveform as image in batch mode OR GUI mode with Tcl/Modelsim commands?
I read the commands about Modelsim (Modelsim SE User Manual) but I didn't find anything.

I am using Modelsim PE 10.4c @ Win7 64bit.

I am very thankful for any help/tips! :)

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your simulation is short enough, saving a bitmap of the full zoom won't help much.

What I suggest you to do is save the waveform by using `vsim -wlf waveform.wlf ...`. Later you can view the by doing `vsim -view waveform.wlf`.

If you used a `wave.do` file to add signals when running the simulation, you must call it when viewing also, i.e.:

```
vsim -wlf waveform.wlf -do wave.do
```

And then

```
vsim -view waveform.wlf -do wave.do
```